# Pass other arguments to on_failure_callback

Tags: airflow

I'd like to pass other arguments to my on_failure_callback function but it only seems to want "context". How do I pass other arguments to that function...especially since I'd like to define that function in a separate module so it can be used in all my DAGS.

My  current default_args looks like this:

```
default_args = {
  'owner': 'Me',
  'depends_on_past': True,
  'start_date': datetime(2016,01,01),
  'email': ['me@me.com'],
  'email_on_failure': False,
  'email_on_retry': False,
  'retries': 1,
  'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
  'on_failure_callback': notify_failure,
  'max_active_runs': 1
}
```

If I try something like this airflow complains:

```
default_args = {
  'owner': 'Me',
  'depends_on_past': True,
  'start_date': datetime(2016,01,01),
  'email': ['me@me.com'],
  'email_on_failure': False,
  'email_on_retry': False,
  'retries': 1,
  'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
  'on_failure_callback': notify_failure(context,arg1,arg2),
  'max_active_runs': 1
}
```

so not sure how to pass arg1 and arg2 to my notify_failure fuction that I would like to define in a separate module that I can simply import into my DAG

Comment: What type of arguments are you talking about? Are they static/consistent between task runs?

Comment: yes they are static between runs, but it seems that the function that I set my on_failure callback cannot have any arguments. I added a bit more info to the top question to hopefully provide some more info

Answer (score 33):

Assuming the args are something you can define at the DAG level, then you can use the partials package. ie:

```
from functools import partial

def generic_failure(arg1, arg2, context):
  # do whatever

default_args = {
  'owner': 'Me',
  'depends_on_past': True,
  'start_date': datetime(2016,01,01),
  'email': ['me@me.com'],
  'email_on_failure': False,
  'email_on_retry': False,
  'retries': 1,
  'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
  'on_failure_callback': partial(generic_failure, arg1, arg2),
  'max_active_runs': 1
}
```

Calling `partial(generic_failure, arg1, arg2)` will return a function expecting however many arguments are remaining in `generic_failure`, which in the above example is just the single param `context`

Comment: This answer should be accepted, its elegant and its working!

Comment: This is a very nice solution. Worked for me.  I was also able to get default values by doing:
partial(failure_callback, named_arg="override_value")

... with the callback function defined like so:
def failure_callback(context, named_arg="default_value"). That way, you can optionally pass the callback as normal (without using partial()) and you will get a default value for your arg.

Answer (score 5):

you can use a nested function for this

```
def generic_failure(arg1, arg2):
    def failure(context):
        message = 'we have a function that failed witg args : {ARG1}, {ARG2}'.format(ARG1=arg1,ARG2=arg2)
        print(message)
        return message
    return failure

arg1 = 'arg1'
arg2 = 'arg2'

default_args = {
  'owner': 'Me',
  'on_failure_callback': generic_failure(arg1, arg2),
}
```

Comment: If I want to loop through these arg1 and arg2 as a dynamic parameters then how we will pass these dynamic parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

As a heads up my work around was to use a lambda function to get the `context` parameter, then just pass that into the function you want on the other side of the lambda:-

`on_failure_callback = lambda context: my_function(context, arg2)`

Full example:-

```
def my_function(context, agr2):
  # function code here

default_args = {
  'owner': 'myself',
   ...
   ...
  'on_failure_callback = lambda context: my_function(context, arg2),
}
```