# Airflow on_success_callback and on_failure_callback not working with data bricks notebook

Tags: airflow, databricks

I want to  customize my DAG to call a datarbicks notebook when it is success or failure. I have created two different functions to call a databricks notebook based on the success/failure cases. success or failure callback function is calling but databricsks notebook is not executing. here is the sample code.

```
def task_success_callback(context):
    """ task_success callback """
    context['task_instance'].task_id
    print("success case")
    dq_notebook_success_task_params = {
        'existing_cluster_id': Variable.get("DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID"),
        'notebook_task': {
            'notebook_path': '/AAA/Airflow/Operators/audit_file_operator',
             'base_parameters': {
                "root": "dbfs:/mnt/aaa",
                "audit_file_path": "/success_file_path/",
                "table_name": "sample_data_table",
                "audit_flag": "success"
            }
        }
    }

    DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id="weather_table_task_id",
    databricks_conn_id='databricks_conn',
    json=dq_notebook_success_task_params,
    do_xcom_push=True,
    secrets=[secret.Secret(
    deploy_type='env',
    deploy_target=None,
    secret='adf-service-principal'
    ), secret.Secret(
    deploy_type='env',
    deploy_target=None,
    secret='postgres-credentials',
    )],
    )

def task_failure_callback(context):
    """ task_success callback """
    context['task_instance'].task_id
    print("failure case")
    dq_notebook_failure_task_params = {
        'existing_cluster_id': Variable.get("DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID"),
        'notebook_task': {
            'notebook_path': '/AAA/Airflow/Operators/audit_file_operator',
            'base_parameters': {
                "root": "dbfs:/mnt/aaa",
                "audit_file_path": "/failure_file_path/",
                "table_name": "sample_data_table",
                "audit_flag": "failure"
            }
        }
    }

    DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id="weather_table_task_id",
    databricks_conn_id='databricks_conn',
    json=dq_notebook_failure_task_params,
    do_xcom_push=True,
    secrets=[secret.Secret(
    deploy_type='env',
    deploy_target=None,
    secret='adf-service-principal'
    ), secret.Secret(
    deploy_type='env',
    deploy_target=None,
    secret='postgres-credentials',
    )],
    )

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    "owner": "admin",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2020, 9, 23),
    "on_success_callback": task_success_callback,
    "on_failure_callback": task_failure_callback,
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=10),
}

==================
Remaining DAG code
==================
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Airflow every operator has `execute()` method that define the operator logic. When You create your workflow Airflow initialize the constructor, render the templates & call the execute method for you. However when you define operator inside a python function you need also to handle this on your own.

So when you write:

```
def task_success_callback(context):
   DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(..)
```

All you did here is to initialize the `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator` contactor. You didn't invoke the operator logic.

What you need to do is:

```
def task_success_callback(context):
   op = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(..)
   op.execute(context)
```

Noting that invoking operators in this manner is not advised. callbacks have no retry mechanism and should be kept simple. Invoking such operator in callback often means design problem. I would suggest to explore the option of custom operator that handles this logic thus avoiding the need to use `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator` in the success callback.

Comment: Thanks Elad for your response and its worked for me.

Comment: @Kiran if solved please accept the answer :)

Comment: Elad,any idea how to pass the parameters to task_success_callback(context) function ?

Comment: @Kiran see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851535/pass-other-arguments-to-on-failure-callback

Comment: Elad, Thanks for your response but it is only for static parameters but I need to pass those args as dynamic parameters. Can you please help me how we can pass dynamic parameters.

Comment: By dynamic you mean what? Where are the value taken from? You can always push the value to xcom and pull it in the callback function.

Comment: suppose if we need to load four tables data from source to destination using DAG and for that we have to create four independent tasks in single DAG right. for four different tasks we need to call callback function for four times(either success or failure)  for that I need to pass parameters and loop the call back function four times.

Comment: @Kiran can you explain what this parameter is? table name? number of rows? what is the point in your ETL that you know the value of this parameter.

Comment: here is sample code to following up to above code

Comment: 'function' object has no attribute 'update_relative'

Comment: @HelenKapatsa I'm not sure if the error you mention is related to the question. There is no dependency between operators in the code snippet thus the update relative doesn't make much sense. This may be different problem in your code. I suggest to open a new question with your code example

Answer (score 0):

```
TableList = collections.namedtuple(
    "table_list",
    "table_name audit_file_name",
)
LIST_OF_TABLES = [
    TableList(
        table_name="table1",
        audit_file_name="/testdata/Audit_files/",
    ),
    TableList(
        table_name="table2",
        audit_file_name="/testdata/Audit_files/",
    ),
    TableList(
        table_name="table3",
        audit_file_name="/testdata/Audit_files/",
    ),
    TableList(
        table_name="table4",
        audit_file_name="/testdata/Audit_files/",
    )
]
for table in LIST_OF_TABLES:
    DEFAULT_ARGS = {
        "owner": "admin",
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "start_date": datetime(2020, 9, 23),
        "on_success_callback": partial(task_success_callback,table.table_name,table.audit_file_name),
        "on_failure_callback": partial(task_failure_callback,table.table_name,table.audit_file_name),
        "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=10),
    }
    WORKFLOW = DAG(
        'test_dag',
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        schedule_interval="30 3 * * 1",
        catchup=False,
    )
```

Comment: Elad,here I want to pass table name and audit_file_name path for call_back functions  for multiple tables loads.

Comment: @Elad, Do you ahev any inputs on this.